# Should i use anything other than float?

Tags: css

I want two add two forms one on left and one on right of the page
and then what i write should be displayed below them.But the problem is it is being shown between the two forms.

```
<form class="login">.....</form>
<form class="signup">.....</form>
<p>This content should be displayed below but it is displayed in space       between the two forms</p>
```

CSS

```
.login{
float:left;
}

.signup{
 float:right;
}
```

Comment: share your working code and what error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of floated element is highly discouraged since there are a lot of other better alternatives that can be used instead. 
Best alternatives are

1. display: inline-block;

CSS

```
.login{
display:inline-block;
}

.signup{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

2. [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

If you still want to use floated elements you can use a clearfix. Clearfix is a way an element automatically clears its child elements. For more information read [How to use clearfix](http://code-tricks.com/css-clearfix-methods/)

Comment: Indentation of code and a fiddle , will make the answer more intuitive and also explaination of what display inline block does will be a +1.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the Width property `width:50%;` it will work

```css
.login{
float:left;
width:50%;  
}

.signup{
 float:right;
  width:50%; 
}
```

```html
<form class="login">.....</form>
<form class="signup">.....</form>
<p>This content should be displayed below but it is displayed in space       between the two forms</p>
```

Comment: but i am using background property also .so it will change the background for the 50%

Comment: No problem it will work , send your code i will help

Answer (score 0):

Adding style `clear:both` to your paragraph will help.

```
.clear
{
  clear:both;
}

<p class="clear">This content should be displayed below but it is displayed in space between the two forms</p>
```